# Test free mem in console on windows

Tags: windows, memory

It's pretty obvious on every platform to see the amount of free mem, but I need to get the value in a batch script.

good old `mem` command is limited to 64MB

What should I use?

Comment: downvote after 7 years from posting with no explanation. I don't like where this community is going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use performance counters. There are a few ways to query performance counters from the command line. Probably the simplest way is with the typeperf command. The following example displays one sample (-sc 1) of the “Available Mbytes” counter from the “Memory” object on the “kennypc” computer.

```
typeperf "\\kennypc\memory\available mbytes" -sc 1
```

There are a variety of performance counters to choose from to get just the results you need. The Performance Monitor snap-in (perfmon.msc) can be used to browse through the available performance counters.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work - probably because i'd have to guess what did they translate "memory" and "avaliable mbytes" into... But I was able to make perfmon run my code

Answer (score 1):

WMI can help.

```
wmic os get FreePhysicalMemory
```

Comment: WMI is often simpler and may be appropriate for your needs however it introduces more overhead especially for performance monitoring. Performance counters are far more efficient. You need to make the choice based on your particular requirements.

Comment: I saw WMI somewhere already, but I didn't have `wmic` command in the system. Do I have to install something? [edit:] It somehow started to install itself when I typed `wmic` without parameters... I don't get it ;)